# Shielding to Block Wi-Fi for Testing No Signal

Tags: emc, wifi

I was trying to conduct a test recently to show that the system I am developing behaved as expected when it can't connect to the Wi-Fi network it is configured for, and then subsequently to test that it resumes normal behavior when it *can* connect to that Wi-Fi network again.

I have a USB cable, a temperature probe, and a 5V power and GND wire connected to the system.

I started by wrapping the system in aluminum foil in hopes of killing the Wi-Fi signal, but my system was able to connect happily. I did a bit of research and found some suggestions on the web that the seams have to be good to block Wi-Fi because the receivers are very sensitive. I was dubious, but went out and bought some double-sided copper tape and wrapped the whole situation in a box covered in overlapping copper tap strips. I went so far as to even cover the entire temperature probe under the tape. So the only things that are exposed to the 2.4GHz radio waves in the world, in principle are the power wires (wired to a Benchtop DC power supply), and the USB cable (connected to a desktop PC). The whole situation looks like this:

[image]

I am startled that my system can *still* connect to Wi-Fi inside that box. It's nominally slower in getting there, but it powers up, connects to Wi-Fi, and sends a packet to my server without batting an eye otherwise.

Is this a common experience? Can anyone explain how this is possible? Faraday cage says what?

Comment: Your power lines are acting as an antenna to transfer RF into the box. You could try using a coax cable (with an appropriate connector feeding through the box) to deliver power to the system. Or (more chancy) routing the power feed through a ferrite bead. Or move the power source inside the faraday cage (use a battery or work in a cage room).

Comment: You're doing it the hard way.  Configure it for a spare AP plugged via Ethernet into the real one.  Take the spare AP up and down.

Comment: That's what I thought... USB cables are shielded IIRC, but those stock red / black power leads almost certainly are not.

Comment: Wouldn't it be *much* easier to get an additional WiFi router/AP, configure your device to connect that that new SSID, and then turn the router off ... ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton yea I know... I got curious is all

Comment: All, the practical advice is great, thanks. I fully understand there are other ways to achieve the same test result. The question is really more about the observed phenomenon rather than the testing goal. Maybe it's not surprising, but it was surprising to me. Also it's kind of a fun picture to post :-)

Comment: It is also possible that WiFi waves are going through that holes where power cables go in. Maybe it's working like an slot antenna? Just a sugestion tho.

Comment: Radio receivers have to work over a pretty insane range of input amplitudes.  If your WiFi AP is anywhere close, then it can get attenuated by 80dB going into the box (and coming out) and things will still work.  If you had to do this for a one-off (or even once a month) test then the battery-in-the-box would probably work.  If you needed to make it work routinely, then a little Faraday cage with feedthroughs on power and maybe even USB would be a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a common experience? Can anyone explain how this is possible?
>   Faraday cage says what?

Copper has a skin depth of 1.3um at 2.4GHz, so it doesn't take much copper to attenuate a wifi signal. To properly build a faraday cage, you cant have apertures (holes), which you have some where the cables come out, or conductors crossing the boundary.

The connection of the power lines is likely conducting emissions that are allowing RF to pass through the chassis. To adequately block these conducted emissions use a line filter. Line filters are special low pass filter that allows DC through the filter but has a capacitor around the outside (that connects to the chassis) to block RF. I'm mostly concerned about RF getting into the chassis, so I use them to severely attenuate RF (to a level that the sensitive analog electronics won't see it). They should also work well for keeping RF inside the box.

[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tusonix-a-subsidiary-of-cts-electronic-components/4209-003LF/410-1088-ND/2079662

Here is a list of [more of them](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/filters/emi-rfi-filters-lc-rc-networks/835?k=rf%20filter%20chassis&k=&pkeyword=rf%20filter%20chassis&sv=0&pv2093=i1&pv2093=i2&sf=0&FV=ffe00343&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=250). Select the approprate one for your attenuation needs at the frequency of interest.

Comment: Side comment, would it be useful to ground the copper in my setup?

Comment: Yes, the line filter should block most of it, it would not hurt to make sure there are no addtional currents, and to send those currents to ground

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it, but I've been here and done this... if you want to knock out the router I'd just buy a shielded tent.

If you get a shielded tent, like this: https://www.tequipment.net/TekBox/TBST86/49/45/1/EMI-Accessories/?v=0, it'll attenuate the 2.4GHz frequencies.  (I own a larger one, and it does work quite well at 2.4GHz).

In my experience, the only ambient that get through a tent like this are cell band signals around me in the 700MHz to 900MHz range in the suburban office we work in.

Comment: FYI, broken link, should be: https://www.tequipment.net/TekBox/TBST86/49/45/1/EMI-Accessories/?v=0; also glad to hear I'm not the only one lol

Comment: @vicatcu, I had an earlier post about building a Faraday cage out of tin foil.  So I'm super glad you tried the experiment!  I ended up buying a big tent ($2000....) and it does work pretty good but those darn cell phone bands do creep in a bit with a high gain antenna in the shielded tent.  It'll knock out your router no problem though if you put it in the tent.